# Raster Weighted Overlay Terminology

Tags: overlay

In a Arcmap raster weighted overlay, if an input data set is designated as "restricted" will overlay calculations not be performed on the "restricted" areas, and those areas will be included in the output? Or will The overlay function ignore the "restricted" data altogether?

I guess I'm just trying to determine how "restricted" could be compared with "NoData". I have heard "restricted" is included in the output, and I have heard it is ignored altogether, and thus want to understand which is more accurate.

Comment: Have you looked at the help page: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-weighted-overlay-works.htm#GUID-7F81B6EF-6AB2-4E22-A2DA-E3780DDDB0EE? It explains the difference between `Restricted` and `NoData`

Comment: thanks.. i have and from my understanding " "restricted" will overlay calculations not be performed on the "restricted" areas, and those areas will be included in the output" would be a more accurate interpretation?